# Sylius 1.12, how to get current order and current cart informtions by using custom Controller or custom bundle?

Tags: symfony, sylius

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVMPW.png)

I would like to retrieve the information from the current order and cart to send them for the creation of a payment session. This process involves collecting essential details such as the items in the customer's cart, the total amount due, shipping information, and any other relevant data necessary for processing the payment.

To accomplish this, I will need to access the backend systems where the order and cart information is stored. This might involve querying a database or interfacing with an e-commerce platform's API. Once I have obtained the required information, I will organize it into a format suitable for transmission to the payment gateway.

Ensuring the accuracy and security of the data during transmission is crucial. I will employ encryption techniques and secure communication protocols to safeguard sensitive information such as credit card details or personal addresses.

After the data has been securely transmitted to the payment gateway, the creation of a payment session can proceed. This session will include all the necessary information for the payment processor to authorize and process the transaction efficiently.

By carefully managing the retrieval and transmission of order and cart information, I aim to streamline the payment process for customers while maintaining the integrity and security of their data

Comment: Is this generated by ChatGPT and co.?

Comment: at least show some code you tried

Comment: $order = $orderRepository->findOneBy(['customer' => $this->getUser()], ['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
        $OrderId = $order->getId();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $customer = $user->getCustomer();
        $firstName = $customer->getFirstName();
        $lastName = $customer->getLastName();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();